# Legality of prescription and schedule 1 drugs in first aid kits

Tags: united-states, drugs

Is it legal to keep small quantities of prescription and/or schedule 1 drugs in a first aid kit? In this situation there would be no prescription or doctor involved. Examples would be:

- morphine
- digitalis
- EpiPen

I looked in various legal resources and could not find a clear answer.

Although I am primarily interested in the legal issues for storage of drugs in first aid kits on land, I am also interested in the same question concerning such drugs being present in a first aid kit on a ship either in US territorial waters or in international waters.

Comment: Would the person possessing the first aid kit hold current prescriptions for each of those drugs?

Comment: @Sneftel No.....

Comment: There's also the issue of who owns the medications and whether they have a prescription for it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are schedule 2 (or below) drugs. Schedule 1 would be things like heroin and ecstasy; https://www.duffysrehab.com/resources/articles/schedule-of-drugs/

Comment: @Richard Yes, I guess so. Morphine is schedule 2, not schedule 1.

Comment: Sadly some of this is covered by state law, such as EpiPens in outdoor education settings. I know of several outdoor programs that have had to eliminate EpiPens from their wilderness first aid kits because of state law. I leave evaluation of the stupidity of such a law to the reader.

Comment: Don't conflate the plant digitalis and the drug digoxin. The former grown in my yard, the latter requires a prescription but is not a scheduled drug under the CSA.  Possession is not criminally regulated like heroin is.

Comment: Note that a first aid kit should not contain drugs in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

### Not for unqualified use

This falls under “[possession with intent to dispense](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/21cfr/21usc/841.htm)”.

It’s OK if the first aid kit is for use by:

- a practitioner authorised to dispense drugs (a doctor, nurse practitioner, paramedic or pharmacist)
- a person registered under the quoted chapter (which can include first-aid officers in remote or isolated locations, like ships)
- the specific person for whom the medication was prescribed